# Getting error in list assignment about index?

Tags: python-3.x, list, index-error

I recently started to study Python, and as I was trying to run a code from a book (with my modification) I got the error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
in : `Names[len(Names)]=name`
```

I read some questions with this error on web but can't figure it out.

```
Names=[]
num=0
name=''
while True :

    print('Enter the name of person '+str(len(Names)+1) + '(or Enter nothing to stop)')
    name=input()

    if name == '' :
        break

    Names[len(Names)]=name
print('the person names are:')

for num in range(len(Names)+1) :
    print('   '+Names[num])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access out of range index
Ex:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l = [0,1,2]
>>> l[3] = "New"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    l[3] = "New"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

For that, you have to `append` new data to the `list`.

```
>>> l.append("new")
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 'new']
```

You can try:

```
Names=[]
num=0
name=''
while True :

    print('Enter the name of person '+str(len(Names)+1) + '(or Enter nothing to stop)')
    name=input()

    if name == '' :
        break

    Names.append(name)
print('the person names are:')

for num in range(len(Names)) :
    print('   '+Names[num])
```

Comment: first of all thanks for paying attention to my question.(all of you guys)
as I asked in comment s from iBug the append function works , and suit for me , just wanted to know problem ( semantic ) behind using my own notation.?( iBug kindly said to not using this code and only use append, but why? :)  )

Comment: Please check 1st half of my answer. `list[index]="new"` we can do this only for modification for particular index which already occupied. But those index on which values are not assigned, we can't add using your method in python. For that you have to go either with `extend()` or `append()` according to your need.

Comment: awsome , got it Harsha, it about that occupying thing which its not working,
thank you so much

Comment: Yup.. exactly.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to append something to an existing list. Why not use `.append()`? This won't give you the IndexError.

```
Names.append(name)
```

Another same error: You shouldn't write `range(len(Names) + 1)`. `range(len(Names))` is enough for you to iterate through the whole list:

```
for num in range(len(Names)):
    print('   '+Names[num])
```

Another suggestion: You don't need the for loop to print the result, *at all*. Just use `str.join()`:

```
print('   '.join(Names))
```

Comment: I noticed it in many posts , but wonder what is the problem I face in this code,to avoid it in future.

Comment: @Mehrdad The problem is, you can't access or assign out-of-range.

Comment: I see the append function will work , and its perfect, 
but wonder the line : 
Names[len(Names)]=name
should give the Names with indice of an integer returned by len() function the value of name, which is getting from input()

Comment: @Mehrdad That's wrong in both Python 2.7 and Python 3. Forget about it if you're coding Python.

Answer (score 0):

just use the append function to insert the new name to the existing list of  names.

Syntax:-

if you want to append 'foo' to the list of existing names i.e 'Names',type **Names.append('foo')**.